# Prove that if $r \le n$, then the number of $r$-subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ is $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I need help to prove that if $r \le n$, then the number of $r$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}.$

Answer (score 1):

You have $n$ choices for the first element, $n-1$ choices for the second,..., $(n-r+1)$ choices for the last. But an $r$-set is invariant under a permutation that is, for example, $\{1,2,3\}=\{1,3,2\}$, so there are $$\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}$$ such subsets.